# Работа с объектами

Tags: javascript

Подскажите как переделать код так чтобы console.log('object is full of properties') выводилась только тогда, когда в объекте два и более свойства?

```js
const testObject = {
    name: 'Dmitriy',
    age: 99,
    location: 'Monaco'
};
function isEmpty (object) {
    for (let key in object) {
        if (object.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            return console.log('object is full of properties');
        }
    }
    return console.log('object is empty');
}
isEmpty(testObject);
```

Comment: Вам просто надо посмотреть сколько в объекте свойств?

Comment: https://qna.habr.com/q/1237730  ответили же

Comment: @MonkeyMutant Если честно впервые такое вижу, но даже если где-то ответили, то как по мне это не повод не пополнять базу данных ruSO :)

Comment: @Monkey Mutant спасибо только что заметил

Comment: @EzioMercer пополнять базу знаний ? ну и каким образом пользователь в сети найдёт этот вопрос/ответ? как думаете сколько впросов в сети с заголовком `работа с объектами`?

Comment: @MonkeyMutant Мало тут плохо оформленных вопросов?) Суть не именно в этом вопросе, а просто, то что где-то что-то ответили не значит, что нельзя здадать этот же вопрос тут

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так это можно сделать:

```js
const testObject = {
  name: 'Dmitriy',
  age: 99,
  location: 'Monaco'
};

const testObject1 = {
  name: 'Dmitriy'
};

const testObject2 = {};


function isEmpty(object) {
  let count = 0;
  for (let key in object) {
    if (object.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      ++count;
    }
    if (count > 1)
      return console.log('object is full of properties');
  }
  return console.log('object is empty');
}

isEmpty(testObject);
isEmpty(testObject1);
isEmpty(testObject2);
```

Answer (score 3):

[Object.keys(obj)](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) возвращает массив собственных итерируемых строковых свойств. Как раз то, что хочется пересчитать в задаче.
Из названия функции "isEmpty" следует, что она возвращает Булево значение (true / false).

```
const isEmpty = obj => Object.keys(obj).length <= 2;
```

Использование:

```
console.log( isEmpty({ a: "AAA" }) ? 'object is empty' : 'object is full of properties' );
// выведет "object is empty"

console.log( isEmpty({ a: "AAA", b: "BB", c: "C" }) ? 'object is empty' : 'object is full of properties' );
// выведет "object is full of properties"
```